# How to resolve "Citation '1' on the page 1 undefined"

Tags: citing

I spent past couple of hours to get citation working on my latex. I am using TexMaker and I tried to compile the document in latex->bibtex -> latex -> latex -> PdfLatex order. However, I only see ? on my outcome pdf file. Could you help me? Thanks !

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{1,
 author = {Mustermann, A. and Mostermann, B. and Mistermann, C},
 year = {2011},
 title = {Using articles in {\LaTeX} documents},
 journal = {Journal}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document} 
\cite{1}\qquad\citet{1}\qquad\citep{1}

\citeyear{1}\qquad\citeauthor{1}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I compile using your sequence I see all the references as well as their `\cite`s in the text.

Comment: Are you maybe missing a `\bibliographystyle` directive in your real document?

Comment: Not sure, if the key may just ve a number or requires a/some characeters in front. This may be compiler dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Does your MWE not work? I can compile it. 
I guess there is a problem in the settings for the compilers. I used following settings and it worked:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
bibtex %
```

pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex

(also using TexMaker)